# How to change component state via Redux

Tags: react-native, redux

In the my application on the home page, I did not use Redux, but simply declared a state = object and changed its state using setState - everything is ok. Help me understand how to work with Redux. Оn the second screen there is a table. How to click on the Update button to change table headers?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
 Button,
} from 'react-native'

import {    
    Table,
    TableWrapper,
    Row,
    Rows,
    Col
} from 'react-native-table-component'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import styles from './Styles/TableScreenStyle'

class TableScreen extends Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.containerT}>
             <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 1}}>
             <Row data={this.props.tableHead} flexArr={[2, 1, 1, 1, 1]} style={styles.headT} textStyle={styles.textT}/>
             <TableWrapper style={styles.wrapperT}>
                <Col data={this.props.tableTitle} style={styles.titleT} heightArr={[28,28,28,28]} textStyle={styles.textT}/>
                <Rows data={this.props.tableData} flexArr={[1, 1, 1, 1]} style={styles.rowT} textStyle={styles.textT}/>
             </TableWrapper>
           </Table>
        </View>
        <View style={{marginBottom: 20}}>
          <Button
            title="Update"
            onPress={() => this.setState({tableHead: ['', 'А', 'B', 'C', 'D']})}
          />
        </View>
        <Button
          title="Home"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  /* What code should be here? */
  return {

    tableHead : ['', 'Store 1', 'Store 2', 'Store 3', 'Store 4'],
    tableTitle: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Total:'],
    tableData: [
                 ['1', '2', '3', '3'],
                 ['4', '5', '2', '8'],
                 ['1', '2', '3', '3'],
                 ['7', '5', '2', '9'],
                 ['13', '14', '10', '23'],
               ]
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
          /* What code should be here? */
          setHeads: (tableHead) => dispatch(setHeads(tableHead))
      }
    }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TableScreen)
```

This is the home screen code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  View,
  Button,
  Text,
  Picker
} from 'react-native'

import { Images } from '../Themes'

// Styles
import styles from './Styles/LaunchScreenStyles'
import Colors from '../Themes/Colors'

export default class LaunchScreen extends Component {
static navigationOptions = {
title: 'Home',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    },
    headerTintColor: Colors.white,
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },

  };
  state = {
         city: 'Dnepr',
         package: 'Set 1',
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>

        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.centered}>
            <Image source={Images.launch} style={styles.logo} />
          </View>

          <View style={styles.section} >
            <Text h4 style={{ textAlign: 'left', color: 'black', marginLeft: 15 }} >City</Text>
            <Picker
              selectedValue={this.state.city}
              style={{height: 50, width: 200, marginLeft: 15}}
              onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
              this.setState({city: itemValue})
            }>
              <Picker.Item label="Dnepr" value="Dnepr" />
              <Picker.Item label="Kiev" value="Kiev" />
            </Picker>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.section} >
            <Text h4 style={{ textAlign: 'left', color: 'black', marginLeft: 15 }} >Set</Text>
            <Picker
                selectedValue={this.state.package}
                style={{height: 50, width: 200, marginLeft: 15}}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                this.setState({package: itemValue})
            }>
                <Picker.Item label="Set 1" value="Set 1" />
                <Picker.Item label="Set 2" value="Set 2" />
                <Picker.Item label="Set 3" value="Set 3" />
            </Picker>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.section} >
            <Button
               title="Table"
               onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('TableScreen')}
            />
          </View>

        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the application already connected to redux? If so, you need to add source code of your action and reducer here. Without it, we cannot answer your question. But I strongly recommend to follow some redux and react-redux tutotrial. Or you will be lost in the code of potential answers.

Comment: Sorry, I used the ignite boilerplate and changed only the home screen and the table screen. I don’t know which files contain the code you are talking about.

Comment: I studied the documentation, but it does not have a complete example, only parts, and I cannot understand how to connect these parts.

Comment: You need to learn basic concepts of redux to go further. They are store, action, reducer. Your mapStateToProps is totally incorrect, it is hard to explain what is wrong, if you do not know basics of the redux.

Comment: I suggest you to read this tutorial first and you will know what I am talking about - https://redux.js.org/basics/basic-tutorial

Comment: Thank you. I will study